# Why isn't my asynctask working?

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading

Sorry if the formatting is weird; I don't know how to format it in here yet, this is my first question.

It works fine if I call the method accessDatabase() from my onCreate() directly but once I try to use an async task I can't get it to work,; it its current form the app just crashes. When I have gotten it to not crash, it still doesn't display the info the accessDatabase() should have.

Any advice is appreciated.

```
package com.example.packagetrackingsystem;


import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * An activity that displays a valid package id's locations.
 * Allows for user to click a button to go into map view.
 * @author kr
 *
 */
public class PackageTextView extends Activity {

    //String url2;
    //JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    static JSONReader jr = new JSONReader();
    static JSONReader jr2 = new JSONReader();
    static JSONReader jr3 = new JSONReader();

    String[] sArr = new String[1];

    private String jsonResult, jsonResult2, jsonResult3;

    static String locationsUrl = "http://ptsuwgb.comxa.com/ptsdbs4/get_all_locations.php";
    static String packagesUrl = "http://ptsuwgb.comxa.com/ptsdbs4/get_all_packages.php";
    static String customersUrl = "http://ptsuwgb.comxa.com/ptsdbs4/get_all_customers.php";

    final static int LOCATIONS = 1;
    final static int PACKAGES = 2;
    final static int CUSTOMERS = 3;

    private MapLocations mapLocation = new MapLocations();
    private String packageId;

    private ListView listViewLocations;
    TextView textViewTest, textViewDateOfShipment;
    Button buttonMapView;

    private ArrayList<String> locationStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<JSONObject> locationsArrayList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    private ArrayList<JSONObject> packagesArrayList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    private ArrayList<JSONObject> customersArrayList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    //ArrayList<JSONObject> packageActivity = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    /**
     * Sets content view, button, and views.
     * Displays package statuses.
     * Generates a Location object for map view.
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.package_text_view);

        textViewTest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTest);
        textViewDateOfShipment = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewDateOfShipment);
        listViewLocations = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewLocations);
        buttonMapView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMapView);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            packageId = extras.getString("PACKAGE_ID");
        }
        else
            textViewTest.setText("null");


        //accessDatabase(locationsUrl, LOCATIONS, jr);
        //accessDatabase(packagesUrl, PACKAGES, jr2);
        //accessDatabase(customersUrl, CUSTOMERS, jr3);

        DisplayAsyncTask dat = new DisplayAsyncTask();
        dat.execute();
        createLocation(locationsArrayList, packagesArrayList, customersArrayList);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Your information has been retieved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        buttonMapView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Class ourClass;
                try {

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putParcelable("MAP_LOCATION", mapLocation);
                    ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.packagetrackingsystem.MainMapActivity");      
                    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(PackageTextView.this, ourClass);
                    ourIntent.putExtras(extras);
                    textViewTest.setText(mapLocation.getLocation(mapLocation.getLength() - 1) + "");
                    //ourIntent.putExtra("MAP_LOCATION", mapLocation);
                    //startActivity(ourIntent);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private class DisplayAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(PackageTextView.this, "Your info is being retieved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            PackageTextView.this.accessDatabase(locationsUrl, LOCATIONS, jr);
            PackageTextView.this.accessDatabase(packagesUrl, PACKAGES, jr2);
            PackageTextView.this.accessDatabase(customersUrl, CUSTOMERS, jr3);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExec() {
            //Toast.makeText(PackageTextView.this, "Your information has been retieved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    /**
     * Fills mapLocation with data.
     * @param locList The locations for the package.
     * @param packList The list to link the location with a customer
     * @param custList The list of customers to look through and find correct customer for a package.
     */
    private void createLocation(ArrayList<JSONObject> locList, ArrayList<JSONObject> packList, ArrayList<JSONObject> custList) {
        // we don't want to display a checked out status on map since a check in would already have been shown
        for(int i = 0; i < locList.size(); i++) {
            if(!(locList.get(i).optString("Status").equals("CHECKEDOUT")))
                mapLocation.addToArray(locList.get(i));
        }

        // getting customer id
        int custId = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < packList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObj = packList.get(i);

            if(jObj.optInt("PackageId") == Integer.parseInt(packageId)) {
                custId = jObj.optInt("CustomerId");
            }
        }

        String street = null;
        String city = null;
        String state = null;
        String zipCode = null;

        // getting address of correct customer, this represents final destination
        for(int i = 0; i < custList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObj = custList.get(i);

            if(jObj.optInt("CustomerId") == custId) {
                street = jObj.optString("Street");
                city = jObj.optString("City");
                state = jObj.optString("State");
                zipCode = jObj.optString("ZipCode");
            }
        }

        String address = street + " " + city + " " + state + " " + zipCode;

        // getting latitude and longitude from address of customer
        Geocoder geoC = new Geocoder(PackageTextView.this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = geoC.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Address location = addresses.get(0);
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        mapLocation.setFinalDestination(latitude, longitude);
    }

    /**
     * Accesses certain parts of the database depending on parameters.
     * @param url the url of the php file
     * @param entity the table of the database to access
     * @param jReader the JSONReader to use
     */
    private void accessDatabase(String url, int entity, JSONReader jReader) {

        try {
            jsonResult = jReader.execute(new String[] { url }).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(entity == LOCATIONS)
            showAddressText();
        else if(entity == PACKAGES)
            getAllPackages();
        else if(entity == CUSTOMERS)
            getAllCustomers();

     }

    /**
     * Gets all customers from the Customer table in database.
     * Adds them to an ArrayList.
     */
    private void getAllCustomers() {
         try {
               JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
               JSONArray jsonCustomersArray = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Customer");

               for(int i = 0; i < jsonCustomersArray.length(); i++) {   
                   JSONObject jsonCustomer = jsonCustomersArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   customersArrayList.add(jsonCustomer);
               }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
    }

    /**
     * Gets all packages from the Package table in the database.
     * Adds them to an ArrayList.
     */
    private void getAllPackages() {
         try {
               JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
               JSONArray jsonPackagesArray = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Package");

               for(int i = 0; i < jsonPackagesArray.length(); i++) {   
                   JSONObject jsonPackage = jsonPackagesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   packagesArrayList.add(jsonPackage);                 
               }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the correct locations based on packageId given.
     * Fills an ArrayList with those locations.
     */
    public void showAddressText() {
        String dateTime = null;
        String status = null;

          try {
               JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
               JSONArray jsonLocationsArray = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Location");
               int currentLocationIndex = jsonLocationsArray.length() - 1;

               for(int i = 0; i < jsonLocationsArray.length(); i++) {   
                   JSONObject jsonLocation = jsonLocationsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                   if(jsonLocation.optInt("PackageId") == Integer.parseInt(packageId)) {
                       //packageActivity.add(jsonLocation);
                       locationsArrayList.add(jsonLocation);
                       String address = convertCoordsToAddress(jsonLocation);
                       dateTime = jsonLocation.optString("DateTime");
                        status = jsonLocation.optString("Status");
                       locationStrings.add(status + "\n" + address + "\n\t" + dateTime);;
                   }                   
               }

               if(locationStrings.isEmpty()) 
                   locationStrings.add("Id not valid");

          } catch (JSONException e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                locationStrings );

        listViewLocations.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
    }

    /**
     * Converts a JSONObject's latitude and longitude to readable address form.
     * @param jsonChildNode The JSONObject to use.
     * @return address the address generated from the JSONObject's information.
     */
    private String convertCoordsToAddress(JSONObject jsonChildNode) {
        String address = "";
        Geocoder geoC = new Geocoder(PackageTextView.this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        double latitude = jsonChildNode.optDouble("Latitude");
        double longitude = jsonChildNode.optDouble("Longitude");

        try {
            addresses = geoC.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("LocationSampleActivity",
                    "IO Exception in getFromLocation()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        address += "\t" + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + "\n\t";
        address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);

        return address;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
04-23 13:49:23.931: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13199): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
04-23 13:49:23.951: D/memalloc(13199): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x50ac3000 size:6733824 offset:6119424 fd:54
04-23 13:49:24.041: D/memalloc(13199): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x512c3000 size:4890624 offset:4276224 fd:57
04-23 13:49:25.552: D/memalloc(13199): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5186d000 size:3129344 offset:2514944 fd:60
04-23 13:49:25.682: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13199): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
04-23 13:49:25.692: D/memalloc(13199): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51c6f000 size:5505024 offset:4890624 fd:63
04-23 13:49:25.743: D/memalloc(13199): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x521f4000 size:6119424 offset:5505024 fd:69
04-23 13:49:25.763: D/memalloc(13199): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x50ac3000 size:6733824 offset:6119424
04-23 13:49:25.763: D/memalloc(13199): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x512c3000 size:4890624 offset:4276224
04-23 13:49:25.763: D/memalloc(13199): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5186d000 size:3129344 offset:2514944
04-23 13:49:26.203: D/memalloc(13199): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x50ac3000 size:3129344 offset:2514944 fd:54
04-23 13:49:28.735: W/dalvikvm(13199): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a6e1f8)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.packagetrackingsystem/com.example.packagetrackingsystem.PackageTextView}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:812)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:579)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at com.example.packagetrackingsystem.PackageTextView.createLocation(PackageTextView.java:199)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at com.example.packagetrackingsystem.PackageTextView.onCreate(PackageTextView.java:98)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-23 13:49:28.745: E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    ... 11 more
```

Not sure how to get the ... 11 more.

Comment: Could you provide LogCat?

Comment: Yes, edited post with logcat.

Comment: i am confused by the title, you dont want your asynctask to work?

Comment: HAHA wow. Fixed now. I would like help getting it to work.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `dat.execute()`, it does not run immediately.

First, the `onPreExecute()` function would be executed on the main thread. So it would execute after `onCreate()` of your Activity.

Then, the `doInBackground()` function would run in another thread. When that is finished, `onPostExecute()` would execute on the main thread.

So you should not call `createLocation()` just after `dat.execute()`. At that time, the data is not fetched yet. You should do it in `onPostExecute()`.

By the way, it's `onPostExecute()`, not `onPostExec()`.

Comment: When I change it to onPostExecute() with "@Override" on top it doesn't like that. It wants me to take the @Override away. Also, I moved the createLocation() into the onPostExec() (I know it doesn't get called yet) but the accessDatabase should call showAddressText() since it's being called from the doInBackground() but nothing is displaying.

Comment: If the debugger doesnt like you adding @Override, its probably because you forgot to add super.onPostExecute(); at the end

Comment: Thanks. My onPostExecute() is showing no errors at the moment. But still nothing displaying for the listView. Is it bad that I'm trying to set it from within my asynctask?

Comment: @user3565929 You may add debug outputs at every step to see what goes wrong. Anything new in logcat?

Comment: Nothing new from logcat. I've attempted to set one of my text view's to "in doInBackGround()" from doInBackground() but the app crashes upon trying to load that activity.

Comment: You should not access the GUI in `doInBackground()`. Try to move your last 2 calls in `showAddressText()` into `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Try to put the code that changes the textview in an "runOnUiThread" method maybe it wont crash

Comment: runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
   {

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
     //Put code here

    }
   });